# How do you make the Windows 8 Metro Photo Viewer open up faster?

Tags: windows-8, images, windows-8.1, photos

I just installed Windows 8.1. Every time I try and open an image, the photo viewer metro app  fills the screen for about a second before the image is displayed.  Is there any way to make the app start up faster?

Comment: all those crappy apps are slow as hell. You can't improve this. MS must tune up their WinRT libraries to load faster.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of anything that will make the app work faster, but if you would like you can always change the way you view the photos. This link will help with that http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-change-default-photo-viewer-on-windows-8/