# Why is viewing pictures in Win 8 so slow?

Tags: windows-8, images

When I doubleclick an image file e.g a png, jpg, gif or similar, and Windows 8.1 should display it with its image viewer, it mostly takes an unreasonable long time for the photo to display. If I for instance instead open the file in paint.exe then the image is displayed instantaneously. It's been like this on 2 or more computer so I don't think that it's a bug in my computer but something with the default image viewer in Windows 8. Do you know anything about this problem? It actually takes longer time to open an image with a new computer running Windows 8 then with a 5 year old computer running windows 7. Why? I think my problem is the same as in this question: [How do you make the Windows 8 Metro Photo Viewer open up faster?](https://superuser.com/questions/685414/how-do-you-make-the-windows-8-metro-photo-viewer-open-up-faster?rq=1)

Comment: What are you using to view/open the image?

Comment: @and31415 I use the default image viewer of Windows 8.1 that displays the image in fullscreen but only after as much as 7-10 seconds of waiting while it displays directly if I open the image in paint or something else than the Windows image viewer. This has happened on 2 independent computers running Windows 8.1.

Comment: The default image viewer is the Photos modern app. Is that what you're using? Does the Windows Photo Viewer exhibit the same issue? Where are the images stored?

Comment: @and31415 The Windows Photo Viewer does not have this issue. It opens and displays the image file directly while it takes at least 5 seconds for the Win 8 I just doubleclick an image in windows explorer and then the viewer opens after an unreasonable long time since I have a fast computer. The images and stores locally on the filesystem and not on the network or on some peripheral device. It takes at least 5 seconds for an image file to display.

Comment: As a workaround you could just set the Windows Photo Viewer as the [default program](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/set-program-access-computer-defaults). Would that be acceptable to you?